# Nodejs Micro service architecture share models in a common project

Tags: node.js, express

I have somewhat large node application and planing to change it to Micro Service Architecture as follows.

```
 Service1
 --controllers
 --services
 --package.json
 Service2
 --controllers
 --services
 --package.json
 CommonService
 --models
 --helpers
```

Can I have all models and other common helpers in separate project and refer them rather than keeping them in all projects.

Comment: Yes you can. Just make npm module with all helpers/services and install->include in main project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to be clear. You can do this two ways.

First you can create in git micro service with all helpers/services that you need. Then just add it in `package.json` like this

`"yourModuleName": "git+ssh://git@github.com:yourName/yourModuleName#Branch",`

Second way looks similar. You can create npm module(https://www.npmjs.com) add in in `package.json` like this

`"yourModuleName": "yourModuleNameFromNPM",`

Then in your main core module just do

`const yourModuleName = require('yourModuleName');`

Dont forget to run `npm install`

And you're done.

Hope this helps.